# Extract date from file name and create a new column with that date auto populated in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am concatenating 100 CSV's with names like XXX_XX_20112020.csv to create one file lets say master.csv

Can I Extract date from each file name and create a new column with that date auto populated for all records in that file? Should I be doing this before or after concatenation and how??

Comment: yes. If they all follow the same `XXX_XX_20112020.csv` pattern then just do `'XXX_XX_20112020.csv'.rsplit('_',1)[-1].rsplit('.',1)[0]` for example. Then parse it to date

Comment: _Can I Extract date from each file name and create a new column with that date auto populated for all records in that file?_ Probably, yes. _and how??_ That's far too broad, and likely off topic. Have you tried anything, done any research? **Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service.** See: [tour], [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: @AMC I did try stuff, didn't mention while asking the question. Will read the links before posting next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

master_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir('folder_with_csvs'):
    # we access the last element after an underscore and all before the dot before csv
    date_for_file = file.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
    date_for_file = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_for_file, "%d%m%Y").date()
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    # Following line will put your date in the `POST_DATE` column for every record of this file
    df['POST_DATE'] = date_for_file 
    master_df = pd.concat([master_df, df])

# Eventually
master_df.to_csv('master.csv')
```

Comment: So we have a list with 100 dates for 100 files in list_dates but how do I make sure each record (in the concatenated file master.csv) has the date associated to the file it is coming from. My column name is supposed to be "POST_DATE"

Comment: I edited so it creates a new column and has for every record the date associated to this file, the list was not very efficient

Comment: Perfect. So, if my list of CSV's get updated next month with 10 new CSV's. Would you suggest I run the whole thing all over again or is there a better approach, Please advise.

Comment: You can then load master.csv in a dataframe at the beginning instead of instatiating an empty one and read your new csvs in their own folder in the loop and they will add themselves to the end

Comment: Can this be implemented from the same folder?

Comment: I mean as long as you move your csvs from the previous month to another folder and that `master.csv` is written to somewhere else this code should work

Comment: Yes, that works for me. Is there a way to put this master.csv in a new folder with datestamp on it everytime we run the code. Auto creating the folder in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

If they all follow the same `XXX_XX_20112020.csv` pattern then just do `'XXX_XX_20112020.csv'.rsplit('_',1)[-1].rsplit('.',1)[0]`

```py
import datetime
file_name = 'XXX_XX_20112020.csv'
file_name_ending = file_name.rsplit('_',1)[-1]
date_part = file_name_ending.rsplit('.',1)[0]

date_part_parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_part, "%d%m%Y").date()
```

So [`rsplit`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html) is just to split the file names on '_' and we do the same to get rid of the suffix i.e '.csv' by splitting on '.'. Now you need to turn the date string into a real date.

Read here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

`strptime` will turn the string into a datetime object when the right format is given.

Now you can make this a function and apply it to all the file names you have.

P.S: `rsplit` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit